# How to track the answers in quiz of camtasia product?

Tags: camtasia

I am using camtasia product. I have created a video and added quizzing along with the video and produced it. I got flash output. I opened it in the browser and played the video. In the quiz section I have entered the answers. Now my question is how to retrieve these answers??. Where these answers will be stored?

Comment: Shouldn't you be asking Techsmith this?

Comment: Usually the SCORM file, which is XML.